# Are there any resorts in the NYC area?

Tags: usa, new-york-city, resorts

Are there any resorts in the NYC area (within an hour of the city)?  When I say resorts, I'm thinking full-service hotels encompassing a large private area, similar to the beach resorts you see elsewhere.

I understand if the answer is no as I can't find any, but I may be looking for the wrong types of terminology, coming out of an Australian tourism system.

Comment: What time of year are you looking? There are several ski towns to the north and west, and there's a few casinos that might suit your needs as well. The Jersey Shore has some beachfront options for the summertime.

Comment: We're looking at the Christmas-New Year's period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at NYC you have to consider that 1 hour (drive) stretches from 30 to 50 miles depending on traffic.  In addition the purpose of the resort as I understand it is to provide activities for the guests that they can't find outside the resort area, they are lower quality, or it is unsafe to step out, which is definitely not the case for NYC.

If you do want to find the resorts in the area you would have to go far in Long Island like

- [Hampton Ocean Resort](http://www.hamptonoceanresort.com/)
- [Gurney's Inn Resort Spa and Conference Center](http://gurneysinn--com.rztrkr.com/?phonalytics=918&rzsource=nc)

You can probably find a [complete list here](http://www.resortsandlodges.com/lodging/usa/new-york/long-island.html) though I have to warn you that you will be looking at 2 hours minimum commute to NYC.  There are resorts on the [Jersey Shore](http://www.resortsandlodges.com/lodging/usa/new-jersey/shore.html) or in [Connecticut](http://www.resortsandlodges.com/lodging/usa/connecticut/index.html) but you are looking at commute a lot longer then one hour (probably 2.5+).

My very serious suggestion is to abandon the private resort idea when it comes to visit NYC as you will miss the whole point of The City(crowds, tempo, etc)

Comment: While staying at a resort to visit NYC is of course folly, -1 for not bothering to look at the excellent mountain and ski resorts that exist in the poconos, catskills, and berkshires, all in the 60-90 minute range to the west or north of the city.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Living in the Poconos and having been to both Catskills I can tell you from the personal experience that the only times you will be able to get 60-90 minutes to NYC would be before 7am or after 10pm.  So if this is OK more power to you.  The reality is that the drive or bus would be 2+ hours and buses don't run frequently enough for one and 2 at around midnight you will have no buses to have anyway.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz And given the location of the Berkshires and also personal experiences of driving there you are looking at closer to 3 hours.